# SVN with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive

I am using SVN in eclipse for a while now and it happened to be, that I have to set up a new machine. After the eclipse install, I'd like to check out my projects from svn. Therefore the question: How does one set up a working SVN plugin for eclipse? I am struggling now for quite some time and have achieved nothing till now. I tried to install subclipse via using http://subclipse.github.io/updates as an 'update site' in the eclipse install software dialog. But after trying to fetch content for about 20 mins, it just states "not a valid update site" and that's it. I tried to look up the URL from the progress view (http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x/content.jar) in my browser and I get a 404 when calling this url. I also tried to install subclipse and subversion from the marketplace. The svn plugin itself (subclipse as well as subversion) does install fine this way. I even get the SVN Explorer View. But the needed connectors do not come with the marketplace install and can not be installed as described in every documentation. Apparently you are supposed to get the necessary connectors within the eclipse GUI with hitting a buttton labeled "Get connectors". But guess what. Ye, this button does not work for me. So how is this supposed to work? Anyone got this running in the last few weeks?

Comment: In the preferences _Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ you probably have an update site `http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x` which is not available anymore and causing this. Remove or disable it and then try with https://subclipse.github.io/updates again (HTTPS instead of HTTP).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I took a look at my installation and yes, the 'broken' link to the update1.6.x was in the preferences as described. Disabling this and another one pointing to a non existing 1.14.x Seemed to work. At least the Installation routine went through without errors. But SVN is still not working properly. It is still missing the mandatory connector.